# Triangle inequality in the metric space $(\mathbb R^2 , d)$ where $d$ is the euclidean distance.

Tags: inequality, metric-spaces

$(\mathbb R^2 , d)$ is a metric space where $d((x_1 , y_1) ,(x_2 , y_2))= \sqrt{(x_1 - x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2 }$.

How to prove triangle inequality for this metric space?

Can anyone please help me ?

**My Attempt :** I was trying to prove it using different inequality results.  One of my result was

$\sqrt{(x_1 - x_3)^2 + (y_1 - y_3)^2 } \leq \sqrt{(x_1 - x_2)^2 + (y_2 - y_3)^2 } + \sqrt{(x_2 - x_3)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2 } $.

Can anyone please tell me how to proceed from here or else you can tell me a new idea.

Comment: If you proved your result for any values of the coordinates, then you only need to swap $y_1$ and $y_3$.

Comment: Yes you are correct.@Gribouillis

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{(x_1-x_3)^2+(y_1-y_3)^2}=\sqrt{((x_1-x_2)+(x_2-x_3))^2+((y_1-y_2)+(y_2-y_3))^2}$ Applying Minkowski's inequality: $\sqrt{(x_1-x_3)^2+(y_1-y_3)^2}\le \sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}+\sqrt{(x_2-x_3)^2+(y_2-y_3)^2}$ $$\Rightarrow d((x_1,y_1),(x_3,y_3))\le d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))+d((x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3))$$I would like to prove a more general result, the triangle inequality in Euclidean metric $(\mathbb{R}^n,d)$ using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.